# Polaris navigation onclick method

Tags: reactjs, shopify-app, polaris

I'm using shopify polaris' Navigation component. The documentation to it is here:

https://polaris.shopify.com/components/structure/navigation

Let's say I setup a navigation component in my `Navigation.js` class like this:

```
<Navigation location="/">
      <Navigation.Section
        items={[
          {
            url: '/path/to/place',
            label: 'Summary',
            icon: 'home',
            selected:true
          },
          {
            url: '/path/to/place',
            label: 'Orders',
            icon: 'orders',
            badge: ''
          },
          {
            url: '/path/to/place',
            label: 'Products',
            icon: 'products',
          },
        ]}
      />
</Navigation>
```

In the link i sent above, it talks about onClick() method. How can I create a method that prints the label of the selected item. So, if they click on the first item, the callback function will get called and print "Summary". I just can't seem to put the pieces together. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass it with `Navigation.Section` items like this:

```
<Navigation location="/">
      <Navigation.Section
        items={[
          {
            url: '/path/to/place',
            label: 'Summary',
            icon: 'home',
            selected:true,
            onClick: () => console.log('Summary')
          },
          {
            url: '/path/to/place',
            label: 'Orders',
            icon: 'orders',
            badge: '',
            onClick: () => console.log('Orders')
          },
          {
            url: '/path/to/place',
            label: 'Products',
            icon: 'products',
            onClick: () => console.log('Products')
          },
        ]}
      />
</Navigation>
```

Comment: Problem. Url will refresh the page